# error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

Tags: c++, c

```
struct reprVectorsTree;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef reprVectorsTree * RHandle;
RHandle create_reprVectorsTree(float **, int , int );
void free_reprVectorsTree(RHandle);
float*  work_decode(RHandle , bool*, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I wrote the interface header file according to the answer here 
[How to use c++ objects in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971063/how-to-use-c-objects-in-c)
, but I get the syntax error? what is missing?

----edit----
I changed it to

```
struct reprVectorsTree;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct reprVectorsTree * RHandle;
RHandle create_reprVectorsTree(float **, int , int );
void free_reprVectorsTree(RHandle);
float*  work_decode(RHandle , bool *, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

now I get the following error on the float* line

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
error C2081: 'bool' : name in formal parameter list illegal
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
error C2059: syntax error : ','
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Comment: Are you sure, that this is the piece of code, which causes the error? If so, which row?

Comment: Could you give us a hint as to which line generated the error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
typedef struct reprVectorsTree * RHandle;
```

You can't just use a struct as if it's a type in C without a typedef (e.g. `typedef struct reprVectorsTree;`)

EDIT: You'll also need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for the `bool` type assuming you're using a recent C compiler, or just use an `int` instead.