# error C2275 RHandle: illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I get the error:

> C2275 RHandle: illegal use of this type as an expression

...when I compile this:

```
int main(){
    int i,j;
    float** tree;
    tree = (float**)malloc(15 * sizeof(float*));
    for( i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
        tree[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        for( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            tree[i][j] = 2;

    RHandle h = create_reprVectorsTree(tree, 8, 2); // error at this line
    // ...
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
struct reprVectorsTree;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct reprVectorsTree * RHandle;
RHandle create_reprVectorsTree(float **, int , int );
void free_reprVectorsTree(RHandle);
float*  work_decode(RHandle , int *, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I followed the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971063/how-to-use-c-objects-in-c).

I am compiling on Visual Studio 2008.

What is the problem?

Comment: How is `tree` defined? Your function takes `float**` as first argument, is that OK?

Comment: This compiles fine for me (GCC 4.6.3)

Comment: I am using VS2008 :(, should I do something different so that it ll work with visual studio?

Comment: @user494461 Ah, see my answer. If you want your current code to compile you'll need to either compile it as C++ or just use a modern C compiler (i.e. not MSVC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but if this is being compiled as C89 you can't have a variable declared in the middle of the scope like that.

```
int main(){
int i,j;
float** tree;
RHandle h;
tree = (float**)malloc(15 * sizeof(float*));
for( i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
    tree[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    for( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        tree[i][j] = 2;    
h = create_reprVectorsTree(tree, 8, 2);
```

Comment: No need to guess, it's Visual Studio, so it's C89 for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your code with

```
#include "my_header.h"
```

using, of course, whatever name your interface file has? As written, the compiler doesn't have any way to know what `RHandle` means.

Please don't summarize code. The mistakes are often in the parts that you "know* are right, and leave out of the summary.