# Calling C++ functions from a C src

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have mixed code base of C/C++ in a MS Visual Studio 2010 project and am trying to call a static function defined in C++ file from a C src file. Right now I get it to work by renaming the C src to CPP (a.c -> a.cpp) Just wondering if there's a more graceful way of getting around it (turning some magic compiler flags on etc) without doing any large scale surgery to the code base(like using opaque pointers as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739999/calling-c-function-from-a-c-code) thread)

*Pls note my code base is pretty complex, I have created this small VS snippet to reproduce the error with bare minimum demonstrable code*

### a.c

```
#include "b.h"

void test()
{
  B::func();
}
```

### b.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

class B{
public:
  static void func();
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

### b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void B::func()
{
  return;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**Error:- In MS Visual Studio 2010**

```
1>c:\.....\b.h(5): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'B'
1>c:\.....\b.h(5): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\.....\b.h(5): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\.....\b.h(8): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

Comment: It's not exactly a pretty solution, but you can also force VC to compile the file as CPP without renaming it. The command line flag is `/TP`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `::` is not valid in C.

Second, including a header is equivalent to copy-pasting a .h file into your C file. Your header must be valid C. Here's some deeper insight:

[How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

[Elegantly call C++ from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c)

Though, my alternative advice is, compile your C as C++. There's a chance it would take minimal or no work to turn out as valid C++.

Comment: I am trying to avoid wrapping around C++ methods

Comment: @Zakir Why are you keen to avoid wrappers? If it's to avoid repeating code, then you can use tools like T4 with EnvDTE (both built-in to Visual Studio) to automatically generate a `.h` file for C based on your C++ code, and also use it to automatically generate a wrapper too.

Comment: @Dai - I will play around with the tools Tnx!